# JS Script doesn't change table row background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

So, first of all, I do have 2 tables. When a row on a main table is clicked a modal window opens with secondary table. The secondary table contains date column. If a date is equal to `"1111-11-11 / 11:11:11"` that means there's an error and so, the row backgroud color should be switched to red.

Here's the code to open the modal window after clicking a row on the first table:

```
$(document).on('click', '#main-table tbody tr', function () {
  var id = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
  openPoolModal(id);
});
```

Nothing complicated. `openPoolModal` function is where I print date to the console as well as try to change the color.

```
function openPoolModal(id){

$.ajax({
url: "/" + id,
success: function(data){
$("#PoolModalHolder").html(data);
$("#personalModal").modal();
$("#personalModal").modal('show');
$('#poolTable').DataTable({
        some DataTables settings;
});
}
});

$("#poolTable tr").each(function(){
  var col_val = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();

    console.log(col_val);

      if (col_val == "1111-11-11 / 11:11:11"){
     $(this).css( "background-color", "yellow" );
  }
});
}
```

And html code that gets returned from an ajax call:

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center" th:text="'Network: ' + ${poolHashrates[0].networkHashrate.id}">Network Id</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table width="100%" class="table table-hover " id="poolTable">

                    <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Pool name</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Date from</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Hashrate [KH/s]</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="poolHashrate : ${poolHashrates}">
                        <td class="text-center" th:text="${poolHashrate.poolDef.name}"> Sample data</td>
                        <td class="text-center" th:text="${@getDataService.formatDate(poolHashrate.poolDef.dateFrom)}">Maven Street 10, Glasgow</td>
                        <td class="text-center" th:text="${@getDataService.formatHashrate(poolHashrate.hashrate)}">999-999-999</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So now, there are actually 2 problems I'm facing. First is, that after clicking the mainTable row for the first time, nothing really happens. When I click second time, the date from the first click gets printed into console. When I click for the third time, the date from second click gets printed and so on.

Second problem is that:

```
$(this).css( "background-color", "yellow" );
```

...doesn't seem to work as it doesn't colour the background.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: I'm not really a JS dev, I know nothing about debugging JS.

Answer (score 0):

use like below

```
$(this).css( "background", "yellow" );
```